# Launch Kazam with `python app.py`?

Tags: python, gtk, kazam

I'd like to test `kazam` (the screencast program) so I try to launch it from the source code.

In the `kazam` directory, I've done:

```
python app.py`
```

but except some warning about `gtk`, nothing happens.
Is it possible?

```
app.py:24: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
app.py:33: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject
/home/campagne/Documents/unstable/kazam/backend/webcam.py:24: PyGIWarning: GUdev was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('GUdev', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, GUdev
/home/campagne/Documents/unstable/kazam/backend/gstreamer.py:35: PyGIWarning: Gst was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstVideo
/home/campagne/Documents/unstable/kazam/backend/gstreamer.py:35: PyGIWarning: GstVideo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, GstVideo
/home/campagne/Documents/unstable/kazam/frontend/window_area.py:29: PyGIWarning: Wnck was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Gdk, Wnck, GdkX11
/home/campagne/Documents/unstable/kazam/frontend/window_countdown.py:29: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, GLib, Gdk, Pango, PangoCairo
```

**EDIT:** Not a complete solution but at least it's not messing with my installation.

I'm using `pip`. In a virtual environment, I can do :

```
pip install -e unstable
```

and it will install it.
(`unstable` is the repo folder where `setup.py` must be inside)
Each code fix, I can do:

```
pip install --upgrade -e unstable
```

Not bad!

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to install Kazam [from repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kazam) (available since 14.04 LTS as version 1.4.4) with all dependencies by the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install kazam
```

and then test it.

If its functionality is not enough, then try to use your source-based version. It will start normally as all dependencies were installed.

Comment: I need the last version (1.5.4) and I need to make some modifications inside the source code (I'll try to solve some bugs). That's why I'd prefer to launch it directly without installing/uninstalling after each code fix.

Comment: The method above will install the dependencies. Do you really want to install all them by hand? You can continue to use source-based version instead of `/usr/bin/kazam`. But it will not start with missed dependencies.

Comment: I've already installed `kazam` (and it works normally) from the repo (v1.4.5). So I guess it's not a missing dependencies